# How to insert items to a UITableView when a UIButton is clicked in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have been practicing with tableViews but I cannot figure out how to insert new items when a button is clicked.

This is what I have:

`BIDViewController.h`:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface BIDViewController : UIViewController

// add protocols
<UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

//this will hold the data
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *names;

- (IBAction)addItems:(id)sender;

@end
```

`BIDViewController.m`:

```
#import "BIDViewController.h"

@interface BIDViewController ()

@end

@implementation BIDViewController

//lazy instantiation
-(NSMutableArray*)names
{
    if (_names == nil) {
        _names = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    }
    return _names;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // add data to be display

    [self.names addObject:@"Daniel"];
    [self.names addObject:@"Alejandro"];
    [self.names addObject:@"Nathan"];
}

//table view
-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView*)tableView
numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.names count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView
          cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    UITableViewCell *cell =  [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"identifier"];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text =  self.names [indexPath.row];
    return cell;
}

- (IBAction)addItems:(id)sender {
    // I thought it was as simple as this, but it doesn't work
    [self.names addObject:@"Brad"];
    [tableView relaodData];
}
@end
```

I thought it was a simple as inserting items to the array and than reloading the data but it doesn't work.

Can someone show me how to add new items to a tableView when a button is clicked?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What behavior are you currently seeing? Does `addItems:` actually get called?  I think you typo'd `reloadData` too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it right,

```
- (IBAction)addItems:(id)sender {
    // I thought it was as simple as this, but it doesn't work
    [self.names addObject:@"Brad"];
    [self.tableView relaodData];
}
```

is the correct way.

Please double check the variable **tableView**, I can't see the declaration of it.

make sure you have,

```
@property(weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
[self.tableView setDelegate:self];
[self.tableView setDataSource:self];
```

and properly  connected the tableView to .nib

Comment: It looks like I was missing the property for the table, it works now. Added property for the table and changed [tableView reloadData]; to [self.tableView reloadData];
 Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track. Make sure you're setting your delegate and data source correctly and your outlet is wired to the button.

Edit: Also fairly certain you can't just @"blah" strings into a mutable array. Try initializing the text as an NSString first, and then pass it in as a pointer.

Comment: Sure you can use @"blah" -- that does create an NSString object.

Comment: @rdelmar: Your correct. I just never do it that way for one reason or another. I guess you can also add bools and other literals as well...thanks for the heads up: http://clang.llvm.org/docs/ObjectiveCLiterals.html