# reload data in UITABLEVIEW object c when clicking button

Tags: ios

I try to search this problem in this site and I found this link [How to insert items to a UITableView when a UIButton is clicked in iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16311393/how-to-insert-items-to-a-uitableview-when-a-uibutton-is-clicked-in-ios). But my problem is, I already copy the code on that link and It doesn't reload the data when I insert a value to my array.

here's the code "ViewController.m"

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property(nonatomic,strong) NSMutableArray * array;
@property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITableView * tableView;

@end

@implementation ViewController


-(NSMutableArray *) array{
    if(_array==nil){
        _array=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    }
    return _array;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
}


- (IBAction)addInfo:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {
    [self.array addObject:@"sample"];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
    return [self.array count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *simpleTableIdentifier = @"TodoListItem";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:simpleTableIdentifier];
    }

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;

}
@end
```

here's the code "ViewController.h"

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>

@end
```

Is there something wrong with my code or there is something that I need to setup to my tableview? I'm very confuse of this and try to figure out the missing part of my code. I'm still studying the code of object c and I'm still noob for this. Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Use logging to see if your count is increasing `NSLog(@"count: %d",self.array.count);` add it in `numberOfRowsInSection`

Comment: I try that but it count 0 when I click my add button. Is there something missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How did you insert the UITableView?, on nib or programatically?, either way you need to flag the table's delegate and datasource, if on nib, right click on table and see that delegate and data source are connected to the files owner, if programatically check

```
self.MyTable.datasource = self
self.MyTable.delegate = self
```

please see how to check if connected [dataSource and delegate should be with a dot, if not click on circle and drag line to file's owner for both]

[table delegate and datasource on interface builder "NIB"](http://www.galloway.me.uk/media/images/custom-uitableviewcell/ib-tableview-links.png)

Also please note that on this image outlet is not connected, you have to connected also to call the reload as you are doing now

edit, check if the button is connected?, put a log or a break point on ibaction for your button to know if is called

edit 2, you have to init the array, are you calling it? do this in view will appear or when you want to use it

edit 3, try this

```
- (IBAction)addInfo:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender {

    if(self.array==nil){
        self.array=[NSMutableArray array];
    }

    [self.array addObject:@"sample"];

    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

Comment: Where can i insert that code you give me? Is it in the info button? and what do you mean by nib? Sorry man I'm student in object c and still studying it.

Comment: hi the nib is the interface builder, right click on the table on interface builder, I edited answer with image of this

Comment: I add that already but I link it to the first owner not the table view.

Comment: Here's the tutorial that I used to copy but this is only for listing http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-tutorial-create-a-simple-table-view-app/. But my idea is to add the list when I click the button.

Comment: thank for the image that you give me. Now I know what is nib. :)

Comment: ok man. I will try this later when I have a computer laboratory in my subject. I'm excited to resolve this. I update you later.

Comment: The only problem is that I didn't link the table view to the View Controller that this display like this @property(nonatomic,weak) IBOutlet UITableView * tableView. Thanks man for your help.